# How to reuse a table in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql

I read those solutions to the similar questions, but it did not seem to work in my case, I tried:

```
WITH tmp AS
( (things below is just an **example** to show that it will return a table)
SELECT 
*clounmname* FROM *tablename*
WHERE *XXXX*
)
SELECT *columnname* FROM tmp;
```

But my mysql workbench says the WITH at the very beginning is misused..
I also tried to add a ; before WITH, but it still does not work..

So I tried:

```
SELECT *columnname* FROM 
( (things below is just an **example** to show that it will return a table)
SELECT 
*clounmname* FROM *tablename*
WHERE *XXXX*
);
```

It runs with no error, but returns nothing..
So I don't know what to do, is there something wrong with mysql workbench?

(Version number of my Mysql worbench is 6.2 for Ubuntu 14.04)
(The query above is just an example, I know AND and other stuffs.)

I even tried:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
SELECT *columnname* FROM 
( (things below is just an **example** to show that it will return a table)
SELECT 
*clounmname* FROM *tablename*
WHERE *XXXX*
);
SELECT *columnname* FROM temp;
```

But nothing returns without any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you are using is known as `Common table Expression (CTE)`. As of now, there is no support for CTE exist in `MySQL`. Alternative solution is to use either `Temporary table` or `inline view`.

So your posted CTE query can be modified with `inline view` as below. Where the result set returned from inner query will be treated as a temporary result set/view.

```
select * from
( 
SELECT *clounmname* 
FROM *tablename*
WHERE *XXXX*
) tab
```

If the result of the inner query will be used more than once then consider pulling that in a temporary table and then use that temporary table like below

```
create temporary table mytab (*clounmname* datatype);

insert into mytab
SELECT *clounmname* 
FROM *tablename*
WHERE *XXXX*;

select * from mytab;
```

Make sure that the `datatype` of the column in temporary table and `datatype` of the column in select list are same.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support the `WITH` keyword at this time.  Common Table Expressions are not available in MySQL yet.

The solution is to use a temporary or derived table or an inline view.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit on how to use a temporary or derived table or an inline view?

Comment: If you are really new with MySQL you should use this site: [Link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/)

Comment: You should mark my answer with the green check to inform future viewers of this post.